# Cache policy, css/js/images how to make them not to load each time i do full postback?

Tags: asp.net, css, image, caching, jquery-plugins

I have made some "select and checkboxes - like mac and so on..." with custom images and styles with jquery, i want them not to be reloaded each time i do full postback.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you are custom creating HTML tags containing CSS and references to images, and this is what you don't want to lose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are normally cached in the browser without much intervention. unless you are using dynamic names or something like that the browser will load them once then pull them from the cache on following requests.

Comment: I dynamically load on $(document).ready CSS styles and bg images

Comment: Ok, That should not be a problem but you can verify  by looking at the browser cache after loading the page, in FireFox its "about:cache". hope that helps.

Comment: didn't got it how does it helps me to load images and reload other stuff, don't forget i work with IE6,7,8,9, etc... FF and all other,

Comment: if you load them dynamically thru jQuery then the browsers are already caching the images, you do not need to change anything to accomplish image caching, the browsers are already doing it for you.

Comment: if they would i would had to put a question here, isn't it?

Comment: they do, check the browser activity with a web sniffer or check the browser memory cache, if an image is loaded either dynamically or not the browser should cache it.

Comment: The problem that isn't IE7 doing me some problems

Comment: ok, is the problem that IE7 is not caching the images or not loading them with the .Load function?

Comment: I know what should we do i will upload the site on iis and i will submit you the link to it you will see on your own.